# Add file permissions with express and node

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have an express API to upload files into a server filesystem with root owner. Is there a way to add the owner and permissions to the file when I upload it, for example: owner: me, access: 644.

My route look like this

```
router.post('/',

imageUpload.single('file'),

function (req, res) {
    res.set('location', encodeURI(urlJoin(UPLOAD_URL, req.file.filename)))
    res.status(req.file.isCreation ? 201 : 204).send()
}
)
```

I use multer to store the files

```
const imageUpload = multer({
storage,
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can change ownership of a file is if you run your script as root (or if you write a SUID root helper program to do that). This is of course if you are talking about the OS access rights. Your backend could serve the file or not based on a cookie, seesion id, a token in some header or anything else in the request. But you won't be able to change the ownership of the file in the file system without root privileges. Consider if that is something that you really need.

If your script runs as root as you wrote in the comments then you can use `fs.chown` to change the owner and `fs.chmod` to change permissions.

See:

- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chown_path_uid_gid_callback
- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_fchmod_fd_mode_callback

Comment: indeed the application will be executed by root owner, but I need to associate the files to a different owner once uploaded to filesystem

Comment: @kyserslick If so then you can use fs.chmod and fs.chown - see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes I found that, tkx.